# How to get realative path for database?

Tags: java, sql, swing, path

I am developing a jframe to store some data in database by using textfields and all. i have following code for database connection. I am using sqlite database.

```
**Connectdatabase.java**

    /*
     * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    package shreesai;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    /**
     *
     * @author DeepRocks
     */
    public class Connectdatabase {

        Connection con = null;

        public static Connection ConnecrDb(){

            try{
                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:G:\\Development\\Project\\database\\shreesai.sqlite");
                return con;
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Problem with connection of database");
                return null;
            }
        }
}****
```

**/* ALL IS WORKING FINE WITH THIS BUT I WANT THAT IS IF I EXPORT THIS PROJECT TO JAR AND MY CLIENT WILL RUN JAR FROM DIFFERENT PATH THEN????*/**

I've tried using this code

```
public class Connectdatabase {

    Connection con = null;

    public static Connection ConnecrDb(){

        try{
            String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+dir+"shreesai.sqlite");
            return con;
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Problem with connection of database");
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Even i tried this one :

```
public class Connectdatabase {

        Connection con = null;

        public static Connection ConnecrDb(){

            try{
                String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
                String maindir = dir + File.separator + File.separator ;
                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+maindir+"shreesai.sqlite");
                return con;
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Problem with connection of database");
                return null;
            }
        }

    }
```

But **NOTHING** i think there must be problem with that double backslashes cause dir returning : **G:\Development\Project\database**. and we want G:\\Development\\Project\\database\\

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ways you're tried are not wrong, but it's right only on your computer, so, the solution is easy, bring the `.sqlite` file inside the `src`, maybe you want create a package named `Database`, it's not required, but it's better.

IF the `.sqlite` file was inside the source would be like that:

`src/shreesai.sqlite`

`....=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:src/shreesai.sqlite");`

Don't want the absolute path too, and avoid using backslashes with directories( `\\` ) because of different windowing platforms, use slash(`/`) instead.

Comment: But user.dir returning path with backslashes :(

Comment: What do you mean by * user.dir returning path with backslashes*?

Comment: I am using System.getProperty("user.dir"); to retrieve the src. but that thing returning the path with backslashes.

Comment: Use `String dir = System.getProperty("...").replace("\\","/");`, however, the way I mentioned don't need `System.getPreo...`, anyway.

Comment: @mKorbel: Why, at the end, they are inside a `jar`, or, shall I expect exceptions? Because I did that on one of my projects.

Comment: I moved my db file from G:\Development\Project\database to G:\Development\Project\src and used ... .getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:src/shreesai.sqlite");